# Duplicate messages on the Azure Service bus if multiple concurrent requests are started

Tags: c#, task, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

I made some testing with an .NET 6.0 API regarding writing messages to the Azure service bus (topic).
In my testing scenario my .NET 6.0 API receives 10 requests ***at once***.
Each request should write a message with a unique identifier to the Azure service bus.
To make my API respond faster, I started with a very naive approach and created an additional task within each call to perform each operation like this:

```
    message.Name = {SOME UNIQUE ID OF MY CALL}
    var task = new Task(async () =>
    {
        var messageObject = new { message.Name, message.Body };
        var messageJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(messageObject);
        ServiceBusSender sender = _serviceBusClient.CreateSender(_topicName);
        await sender.SendMessageAsync(new ServiceBusMessage(messageJson));
    });
    task.Start();
```

Now the user does not have to wait for the message to be sent, but directly receives a posivite response even before the message has successfully been put on the bus.

What I expected:

- I expected that only a subset or none of my 10 messages will be sent successfully to the bus, because after the request has finished, all objects (including my inline-task) should be destroyed.
- Instead I noticed that all 10 messages are successfully sent to the bus. But with ***double unique identifiers***.

So if I have those unique ids:

0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9

The bus ends up receiving always ten messages, but some uids are double, others are not sent at all, like:

0, 0, 0, 1, 4, 5, 6, 6, 9, 9

If all calls are not sent concurrently, but sequencelly I get:

0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 (what makes sense)

I have two concrete questions now:

- Why are always all messages transferred to the bus, even though the main Task of the request ends before the inner task ends?
- Why are some messages double? Others are not transferred at all?

Any ideas?

By the way: In my production scenario I am not doing it like this. I am using a "BackgroundService" to perform background jobs like that.

Comment: The above code isn't enough to describe the problem, but it is almost certainly a threading issue related to the message.Name assignment. Is that your complete code?

Comment: I’m not sure why do you use Task here to kick off random sending, knowing some sends would not make it. What’s the real use case? Usually, you’re passing request to a queue to complete the request **without** losing the request data. As was mentioned by @DavidL, the code snippet is not sufficient to help you.

Comment: Yes - in my production scenario I am using a queue (or more precisely: A channel). I just observed the bahaviour of my test and did not understand it. For this reason I asked. Just for my understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `Task.Start` your task is not necessarily executed immediately, it is scheduled and will run at some non-deterministic point in the future.  When it executes, it will capture the current value of `message.Name`, not the value that existed at the time you created the task.

To capture the current `message` instance at the time you create the task, you'd want to use a form similar to:

```cs
    message.Name = {SOME UNIQUE ID OF MY CALL}

    var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(async state =>
    {
        var messageParam = (MessgeType)state;
        var messageObject = new { messageParam.Name, messageParam.Body };
        var messageJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(messageObject);
        
        await using var sender = _serviceBusClient.CreateSender(_topicName);        
        await sender.SendMessageAsync(new ServiceBusMessage(messageJson));

    }, message);
```

> Why are always all messages transferred to the bus, even though the main Task of the request ends before the inner task ends?

When you call `Task.Start`, you're queueing the task for execution, where the queue is owned by constructs related to the thread pool.  These are not bound to the lifespan of your code, they're part of the runtime.  Your `task` variable is no longer in scope, but the instance that it references is still held by the runtime.

It does leave you in a position where exceptions go unhandled and unobserved.  Depending on when they occur, the severity, and the host environment, in some extreme cases the exception may crash the host process and/or impact the throughput of the thread pool and you'd have little understanding of why.

> ServiceBusSender sender = _serviceBusClient.CreateSender(_topicName);

This line is also problematic.  You're creating a new sender for each operation to the same topic, which is going to perform poorly and increase resource use.  The `ServiceBusSender` is intended to be long-lived and reused.  I'd strongly advise caching and reusing your sender whenever publishing to `_topicName`.

You are also not closing or disposing the sender.  This is going to leave its AMQP link open and consuming network resources unnecessarily until it idles out.  Even then, you'll have pending clean-up waiting for the finalizer.

Comment: "but the instance that it references is still held by the runtime" - can you explain this more? Where is this "instance" if the task variable went out of scope? In my production scenario I am caching the sender - but oops... closing or disposing. I will read about the best practices here. Thank you!

Comment: A variable points to something, in the case of `task`, the thing that it is pointing to is  location on the heap.   When you call `Task.Run` here, the scheduler makes a new pointer to the same location on the heap.   When your code ends, `task` is out of scope and no longer points anywhere, but because there is another reference to it, the heap memory cannot be collected and lives on.  The scheduler reference is still valid and the scheduler will do its job with no understanding or care about your local `task` variable.

Comment: Okay - thanks. That is interesting background knowledge. About that scheduler I need to read more to get a deeper understanding

Comment: Another question: If I cache my senders for the same topic, when should I call DisposeAsync? After each sent message and then re-open or how do I decide when to dispose?

Comment: Calling  `CloseAsync` or `DisposeAsync` on the `ServiceBusClient` will clean up any children that were spawned from it.   We're recommend closing out the client as part of your application's cleanup process.

Comment: So the whole lifetime my API is running (several weeks could be) I don't have to call those methods? I can reuse the sender so long?

Comment: Yes; the clients will manage network resources internally and let things go idle when not used, reconnecting when operations are being requested.

Comment: "You are also not closing or disposing the sender. This is going to leave its AMQP link open and consuming network resources unnecessarily until it idles out." So your comment was only referencing my case when I was opening too many senders. Now, when I'm caching them, closing is only needed on app shutdown.

Comment: Correct.   Since you're caching and have a constant reference, the client/sender will manage their own network resources.    The concern was that you were orphaning senders without telling them "we don't need you anymore"

Comment: Perfect. This answers my question finally. Thanks a lot! :)